# Inno Setup - No constant on saved games

Tags: inno-setup

Greetings first time in here, I've got a question I'm making a simple installation on Inno, but I need some files to install on the default user/saved games folder, I'm unable to find a constant which fits this, anyone knows a turn around to do it?

Comment: Can you give  us an example of a real path for *"defualt user/saved games folder"*?

Comment: There isn't one in 6.0.3. 6.0.4 will have `{usersavedgames}` constant (see http://jrsoftware.github.io/issrc/whatsnew.htm).